# Assign a Dictionary Key to a Given List Using Python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Can I assign a dictionary key to a list OR list of lists. Then take averages, cov, etc it:

```
input={'03439', '03440'}
list of list= [[PersonA, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11],[PersonB, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16]]
```

Desired Output

```
{'03439': [PersonA, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11],'03440':[PersonB, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16]}
```

If I wanted to take the average values of the above, can I do so even with part of this being string and the other values?

Comment: What is `dct`? The input? The output? BTW, `dct` is a `set`. Applying the average to elements of different types has nothing to do with python, but with the concept of comparing apples to starfish

Comment: It _feels_ kind of weird to have "keys" in a set and "corresponding" (?) values in a separated list. Mind explaining where your data comes from ?

Comment: Sets are unordered so unless you sort or do some custom ordering then there is no way to know what will be paired

Answer (score 2):

In case you wanted to calculate the average there and then you could do

```
>>> PersonA = 'Pino'
>>> PersonB = 'Gino'
>>> i=('03439', '03440') # tuple
>>> l=[[PersonA, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11],[PersonB, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16]]
>>> av={k:[v[0], sum(v[1:])/(len(v)-1)] for k,v in zip(i,l)}
>>> av
{'03439': ['Pino', 9.0], '03440': ['Gino', 14.0], }
```

Nota Bene: for the zipping to work `input` must be an iterable which can keep the order of its elements, e.g. a tuple or a list. Sets and plain dictionaries cannot do it.

And the answer is no, integers cannot be summed with strings

Answer (score 0):

Use `zip` and just construct a `dict`:

```
>>> dict(zip(input, list_of_lists))
{'03439': ['PersonA', 7, 8, 9, 10, 10], '03440': ['PersonB', 12, 13, 14, 15, 16]}
```

Comment: Nota Bene: for the zipping to work `input` must be an iterable which can keep the order of its elements, e.g. a tuple or a list. A set cannot do it.

Answer (score 0):

Using izip and list comprehension

```
from itertools import izip
     [dict([(x,y)])for x,y in izip({'03439', '03440'},[['PersonA', 7, 8, 9, 10, 11],['PersonB', 12, 13, 14, 15, 16]])]
```

output

```
[{'03439': ['PersonA', 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]}, {'03440': ['PersonB', 12, 13, 14, 15, 16]}]
```

Comment: Nota Bene: for the zipping to work `input` must be an iterable which can keep the order of its elements, e.g. a tuple or a list. Sets and plain dictionaries cannot do it.